# Problem with authentication on java ws

Tags: c#, java, web-services, authentication

I have application in C# that consume Java WS. Everything worked fine until WS was configured to use authentication. Now I should user login i password to execute methods from WS but I'm not sure how to do it. 
I've try

```
var client = new MyBeanClient();
                    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
                    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";
                    client.addConsumer("whatever", "", "", "");
```

But I get 
SecurityMessageException-{"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from
the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."}
InnerException - (WebException) - {"The remote server returned an error:
(401) Unauthorized."}.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
credentialCache.Add(new Uri(client.Url), "NTLM", credentials);
client.Credentials = credentialCache;
client.addConsumer("whatever", "", "", "");
```

---

UPDATE:

<strike>Sorry in my first post I thought you were using `wsdl.exe` to generate the client proxy. For a WCF client you need to configure the endpoint:</strike>

```
var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://example.com/myWindowsAuthN");
var client = new MyBeanClient(basicHttpBinding, endpoint);
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "domain";
client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "username";
client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "password";
```

---

UPDATE2:

I've used the following configuration to invoke web services protected with NTLM authentication. In app.config of the client put the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="NtlmBinding">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint
      address="http://example.com/SomeWindowsAuthenticatedService"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="NtlmBinding"
      contract="IOperationContractOfTheService"
      name="WSTestSoap" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and then you could set the corresponding credentials before invoking the method:

```
using (var client = new MyBeanClient())
{
    client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = 
        new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "DOMAIN");
    client.addConsumer("whatever", "", "", "");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately on client there is no Credentials field. There is only ClientCredentials property but it's readonly :/ Also client doesn't have property Url :/

Comment: Still have the same problem :/ SecurityMessageException :/

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me what should I write as "DOMAIN" ??

Comment: The name of the domain your account belongs to. In order for NTLM authentication to work you need to have an Active Directory setup.

Comment: I'm not sure why I have to use Domain account ?

Comment: Do I need name of the account configured on server which contains this WS ?